# Calculate sum of array one array attribute and constructing by key

Tags: javascript

I have an object

```
let returnObj = {
   test_on_Home_Page: {
     page: 'Home Page',
     total_sum: -141.16874354518953,
     top_url: null
   },
  test_on_Product_List: {
     page: 'Product List',
     total_sum: -147.16874354518953,
     top_url: null
   },
  testOther_on_Home_page: {
     page: 'Home Page',
     total_sum: -48.16874354518953,
     top_url: null
   },
}
```

I want to calculate total_sum of Object keys by pages, like this

```
 {
    HomePage : -189.33744
    ProductList : -147.168743
  }
```

I have tried

```
let totalCart = 0;

for(let errorName of Object.keys(returnObj)){
    if(returnObj[errorName]['page'] == "Cart"){
    totalCart += returnObj[errorName]['total_sum'] 
    }
 }
```

But that doesn't look dynamic to me.

Can this be done with one line
With something like this

```
 let list = [];
 
 for(let errorName of Object.keys(returnObj)){
    list[returnObj[errorName]] += returnObj[errorName]['total_sum']
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate `values`, not `keys`:

```
let sums = {}

for (let obj of Object.values(returnObj))
    sums[obj.page] = (sums[obj.page] ?? 0) + obj.total_sum
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use more of a functional aproach

```
const sums = {}
Object.values(returnObj).forEach(item => {
  sums[item.page] = (sums[item.page] ?? 0) + item.total_sum
})
```

Using the lodash lib:

```
const sums = {}
_.values(returnObj).forEach(item => {
  sums[item.page] = (sums[item.page] ?? 0) + item.total_sum
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using `Array.prototype.reduce` on `Object.values(returnObj)`:

```js
const o = {
  test_on_Home_Page: {
    page: 'Home Page',
    total_sum: -141.16874354518953,
    top_url: null
  },
  test_on_Product_List: {
    page: 'Product List',
    total_sum: -147.16874354518953,
    top_url: null
  },
  testOther_on_Home_page: {
    page: 'Home Page',
    total_sum: -48.16874354518953,
    top_url: null
  },
}

const sums = Object.values(o)
  .reduce((a, { page: p, total_sum: s }) => ({...a, ...{ [p]: (a[p] ?? 0) + s } }), {});

console.log(sums);
```